# Using a 3D hankel matrix to index a 3D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, indexing

Given the following three dimensional hankel matrix:

```
hankel_matrix = hankel(1:21, 21:999);
hankel_matrix = repmat(hankel_matrix, [1 1 no_of_weighted_composites]);
```

And the matrix:

```
composites_collection = permute(reshape(data_composites.', size(data_composites, 2),1,[]),[2 3 1]);
```

where data_composites is a 999 x 56 matrix.

Essentially what I want to achieve is use the hankel matrix to index the 56 different pages of single rows found in the composites collection.

I had assumed this would be as easy as data_composites_collection(hankel_matrix) but that simply uses the first page of data_composites_collection and repeats this for all 56 pages.

My current implementation is:

```
function subsequent_hankel_index = createMovingSnapshotsOfValues(~, matrix_of_numbers, data_composites, windows, no_of_weighted_composites)

        data_composites_collection = permute(reshape(data_composites.', size(data_composites, 2),1,[]),[2 3 1]);
        hankel_index = NaN(260, 999, no_of_weighted_composites, size(windows, 2));

        for window_size = 1:size(windows, 2);
            for composite = 1:no_of_weighted_composites;
                hankel_matrix = hankel(1:windows(window_size), windows(window_size):length(matrix_of_numbers));

                desired_row = data_composites_collection(:,:,composite);
                [rows, columns] = size(desired_row(hankel_matrix));

                hankel_index(1:rows,1:columns,composite,window_size) = desired_row(hankel_matrix);
                subsequent_hankel_index = hankel_index;

            end
        end

    end
```

However, this is incredibly slow for the amount of data I have. I have assumed vectorising the above would greatly help the speed of my programme. Any tips or approaches to the indexing would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to achieve, maybe using a small example? What exactly do you want to do with `data_composites`? I don't understand what you mean by "56 different pages of single rows" and how this relates to a Hankel matrix (which indexes anti-diagonals, not rows).

Comment: @A.Donda thanks for getting back to me. What I am doing is using the hankel matrix as a shifting window i.e. first column being first window (1-21), second column being second window (2-22).  
data_composites_collection is a 1x999x56 matrix, and I want to use the hankel matrix to index data_composites_collection to create the values for the moving windows.  
example:  
`hankel_matrix = hankel(1:3,3:5)`  
`hankel_matrix = repmat(hankel_matrix, [1 1 3])`  
`composites = rand(1,5, 3)`  
`composites(hankel_matrix)`  
Where the last bit would index composites for all dimensions

Comment: Ok, so you want to create a sequence of overlapping submatrices of `data_composites_collection`, each of size 21x56. And then what do you want to do with these submatrices? I can't tell from you function. Also it appears you do that for different window sizes, so it is not really a wonder that it takes ages. I think it would be best if you could add some background on what you want to achieve with all this.